# Static methods on ASP.NET web sites

Tags: asp.net, static-methods

i was wondering.. if i have a static method on an asp.net web site (plain vanilla), is that accessible by all users of all sessions?

I guess what i am saying is the single instance of a method available to **each** client? or is there **1** instance for **all** clients for the site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static value is the same for all users on the same pool.

Different pools have different static values.

The session have nothing to do with the static values, and the users that are on the same pool have the same static values.