# Static variable Behaviour in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, static-variables

I have a OperationHelper class which is as follows:

```
public class OperationHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Add Operation value
        /// </summary>
        public static bool AddOperation { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Edit Operation value
        /// </summary>
        public static bool EditOperation { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Delete Operation value
        /// </summary>
        public static bool DeleteOperation { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Select Operation value
        /// </summary>
        public static bool SelectOperation { get; set; }
    }
```

on each request this values are re-assigned. when i run this locally it works properly.
but when i published the code some values are not get assigned or not working as it should work.

So want to know the behavior of the static variable in Asp.Net with C#.

are static variable equal to global variable which is accessible to all user? If it is set by user A to true can user B get that value as True or it has different instance of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So want to know the behavior of the static variable in Asp.Net with
>   C#.
>
> are static variable equal to global variable which is accessible to
>   all user? If it is set by user A to true can user B get that value as
>   True or it has different instance of the variable.

The behavior is like that only if your **run your site under one working process** on your pool.

If your pool have **more than one working process, then each process have their static values**, and is unknown to you what process is given to each request, to each user. And process together they are not communicate.

So let say that you have a pool with 4 working process.

UserA ask for a page, Process 1 is replay and set a static value to A.
UserB ask for a page, Process 1 is replay and the static value is A.
UserA ask for a page, Process 2 is replay and the static value is not set.

and so on.
More on the subject:
[Lifetime of ASP.NET Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919095/lifetime-of-asp-net-static-variable/8919336#8919336)
[Where are static variables stored in asp.net aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559529/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-asp-net-aspx-page/5559554#5559554)
[Using static variables instead of Application state in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038)
[Static methods on ASP.NET web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779617/static-methods-on-asp-net-web-sites/2779646#2779646)
[Asp.net static object appears sometimes as non global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721883/asp-net-static-object-appears-sometimes-as-non-global/15722751#15722751)

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `static` variables is that they are being created  as soon as the code they belong to is reached. To solve your problem, consider a `static constructor` for your class to properly initialize all values to your desire

```
public class OperationHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Add Operation value
    /// </summary>
    public static bool AddOperation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Edit Operation value
    /// </summary>
    public static bool EditOperation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Delete Operation value
    /// </summary>
    public static bool DeleteOperation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Select Operation value
    /// </summary>
    public static bool SelectOperation { get; set; }

    static OperationHelper() {
    //initialize your static variables here
    }
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) for a reference on `static` constructors.

Comment: If it is set by user A to true can user B get that value as True or it has different instance of the variable.?

Comment: `static` objects are not bound to an instance, they have the same value for every body.

Comment: In ASP.NET not in particular, as the website is created for every request from a different browser, so it won't happen that someone in the USA will have the value as someone in India, for example.

Answer (score 1):

static variables are only created once. so `userB` will get same instance of the variable to answer your question.

More on this have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563171/asp-net-c-sharp-static-variables-are-global).

Answer (score 0):

you need to consider session that will give you different value for each user accessing the site